# popup testing with Watin, build in framework

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, frameworks, watin

Working with C#, vs 2013 and Watin.

To explain the question I will give the scenario:

1. Open IE, goto url "start app".
2. URL starts a local application.
3. closes the IE instance that starts the app.

This local application is a web app... but, in the task manager it is shown as a "framework presentation layer component".

I can't find the app with:
IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo(Find.ByUrl("http://something"));
Guess, because it isn't a real popup. Also, it isn't recognised as a browser.

The objects in the application when I check them with "inspect.exe": frameworkID = InternetExplorer.

Any idea's?

Comment: Can you post the code that opens the popup and starts the application?

Comment: http://appsite.local/link.tn?StartPage=&OpenedWithFrameworkUi=1 More I can't see.

Comment: I'm not looking for the URL. What C# or JavaScript or C++ or VBScript code is used to open the pop up window. There is no public domain named called `appsite.local`.